# Update user status by c# and php

Tags: c#, php

I am programming a c# application.

I used php for my server side and mysql database for keep accounts data.I can access my mysql database by WebRequest and POST method.
I update account status by login to prevent other ones login but i do not know how to know user exit time.

I know i can program c# for exit event but what if user exit unexpectedly.It seems a little risky because if i exit with a special condition user will be logged and no one can login even last user so i think its better to set a expire time in server side.

I update my user status in a time range but how can i program my database to change a record when there is no user update?Can i do it by php?SQL queries?

Thanks.

Comment: Use expire when timed out strategy instead of destroy when exit strategy. As you know, the app can closed without any related events.

Comment: @donggas90 How?

Comment: In your server, add a datetime which recording the user was last vaildated time. And client pinging to validate its connection in some interval. Then, the server can monitoring the datetimes to determine which users should unloaded from memory.

Comment: @donggas90 Thanks that is a nice solution

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can track form close event or user logout. Therefore you can track user exit. Consider `Activated` event and/or `LostFocus` event as you can do nothing more if user exits unexpectedly as if the PC lost power.

Comment: I know but what if user exit unexpectedly ?

Comment: Then save keep the track of last focused time on the form and Control.LostFocus event

Comment: It seems a little risky because if i exit with a special condition user will be logged and no one can login even last user so i think its better to set a expire time in server side.

Comment: Then maybe you should use C# session timeout?

Answer (score 0):

In php you can use session to keep the user's status. I would recommend setting a number of the number of active sessions based on your question so that if someone tries to login else where they would get an error or the they managed to login the other active user would automatically log out

Comment: Use php session?So, this will expire in 24 min after last update?Is it secure enough?Can i update database records by session expire?

Comment: Php  sessions can last as long as you tell them to last and can be as secure as you make it to be. For a beginner in my opinion, no, but there are tutorials on the web to help you secure it. You generate a token and store in the database if you want.
Here is a resource to help you expire the session: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Comment: Thanks and can i command to do something when sessions expire?

Comment: Yes sir, you can

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this with TRIGGER in Database to track idle time and logout user from database. If user was idle on the screen you can update Database with in the time interval you defined in trigger from UI.

```
CREATE
    [DEFINER = user]
    TRIGGER trigger_name
    trigger_time trigger_event
    ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW
    [trigger_order]
    trigger_body

trigger_time: { BEFORE | AFTER }

trigger_event: { INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE }

trigger_order: { FOLLOWS | PRECEDES } other_trigger_name
```

[For More info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: Can you specify more?How it can track user activities?TRIGGERs just work after a INSERT ,.. queries

Comment: Which app you are using winform  or console app ?

Comment: Winform application